# Python3 CSV Writer produces a binary file

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I am trying to write a simple caching mechanism using a CSV file.
However, for a single instance, the CSV produces is binary instead of text.
This is the code:

```
import os
import csv
import logging
import requests


logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class CWS:
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.key = key
        self.url = 'https://contextualwebsearch-websearch-v1.p.rapidapi.com/api/Search/WebSearchAPI'
        self.headers  = {'x-rapidapi-key': key,'x-rapidapi-host': 'contextualwebsearch-websearch-v1.p.rapidapi.com'}
    
    def search(self, query):
        page = 1
        snippets = []
        done = False
        total = total_count = 0
        while not done:
            querystring = {'q':query,'pageNumber':page,'pageSize':50,'autoCorrect':True}
            response = requests.request("GET", self.url, headers=self.headers, params=querystring)
            
            if response.status_code == 200:
                j = response.json()
                total_count = j["totalCount"]
                values= j['value']
                for value in values:
                    description = value['description']
                    snippets.append(description)
                total += len(values)
            else:
                done = True
            page += 1
            if total >= total_count*0.2:
                done = True
            logger.debug('(%s, %s, %s, %s)', page, total, total_count, int(total_count*0.2))

        return snippets


class CacheSearch:
    def __init__(self, ws, path):
        self.ws = ws
        self.path = path
    
    def search(self, query):
        filename = f'{self.path}/{query}.csv'
        snippets = []
        if os.path.exists(filename):
            logger.info('Cache file %s', filename)
            with open(filename, 'rt', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csv_file:
                reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
                for row in reader:
                    snippets.append(row[0])
        else:
            logger.debug('Cache file %s does not exist...', filename)
            snippets=self.ws.search(query)
            logger.debug('Snippets loaded from Search Engine')
            with open(filename, 'wt', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csv_file:
                writer = csv.writer(csv_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
                for s in snippets:
                    #setence = s.replace('\r','').replace('\n','')
                    #setence = setence.encode('utf-8').decode()
                    writer.writerow([s])
            logger.debug('Snippets stored in %s', filename)
        return snippets


cws = CWS(config.key)
cache_ws = CacheSearch(cws, 'cache')
snippets = cache_ws.search('tool')
```

After running my simulation this is the result (using file  -i *):

```
cache/asylum.csv:     text/plain; charset=us-ascii
cache/automobile.csv: text/plain; charset=us-ascii
cache/bird.csv:       text/plain; charset=us-ascii
cache/boy.csv:        text/plain; charset=us-ascii
cache/brother.csv:    text/plain; charset=us-ascii
cache/car.csv:        text/plain; charset=us-ascii
cache/cemetery.csv:   text/plain; charset=us-ascii
cache/chord.csv:      text/plain; charset=us-ascii
cache/coast.csv:      text/plain; charset=us-ascii
cache/cock.csv:       text/plain; charset=us-ascii
cache/crane.csv:      text/plain; charset=us-ascii
cache/food.csv:       text/plain; charset=us-ascii
cache/forest.csv:     text/plain; charset=us-ascii
cache/fruit.csv:      text/plain; charset=us-ascii
cache/furnace.csv:    text/plain; charset=us-ascii
cache/gem.csv:        text/plain; charset=us-ascii
cache/glass.csv:      text/plain; charset=us-ascii
cache/graveyard.csv:  text/plain; charset=us-ascii
cache/hill.csv:       text/plain; charset=us-ascii
cache/implement.csv:  text/plain; charset=us-ascii
cache/jewel.csv:      text/plain; charset=us-ascii
cache/journey.csv:    text/plain; charset=us-ascii
cache/lad.csv:        text/plain; charset=us-ascii
cache/madhouse.csv:   text/plain; charset=us-ascii
cache/magician.csv:   text/plain; charset=us-ascii
cache/midday.csv:     text/plain; charset=us-ascii
cache/monk.csv:       text/plain; charset=us-ascii
cache/noon.csv:       text/plain; charset=us-ascii
cache/oracle.csv:     text/plain; charset=us-ascii
cache/rooster.csv:    text/plain; charset=us-ascii
cache/shore.csv:      text/plain; charset=us-ascii
cache/slave.csv:      text/plain; charset=us-ascii
cache/smile.csv:      text/plain; charset=us-ascii
cache/stove.csv:      text/plain; charset=us-ascii
cache/string.csv:     text/plain; charset=us-ascii
cache/tool.csv:       application/octet-stream; charset=binary
cache/voyage.csv:     text/plain; charset=us-ascii
cache/wizard.csv:     text/plain; charset=us-ascii
cache/woodland.csv:   text/plain; charset=us-ascii
```

Only a single file is stored in binary mode, This leads to the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 93, in <module>
    main(args)
  File "main.py", line 75, in main
    word_a_neighborhood = extract_neighborhood(word_a, cache_ws, args.n)
  File "main.py", line 26, in extract_neighborhood
    snippets = ws.search(target_word)
  File "/mnt/d/git/semantic/search.py", line 62, in search
    for row in reader:
_csv.Error: line contains NUL
```

Comment: Need a [mcve], at least the part of the simulation that writes the file incorrectly.  That also includes the minimal code to make your class work (imports, etc.)  Don't give snippets of code...ideally give working code we can cut-n-paste and try without having to modify it.  What is `ws` for example?

Comment: Added the complete code, ws stands for Web Search, in this case, is a REST API named contextual web.